# Two separte web apis in same project with separate configs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to have two web API's running in the same web project, with separate configuration?

I'm having problems because if I change System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration then my changes affect the other web API.

Comment: Interesting, why not two separate api projects in a shared solution?

Comment: When a new request comes in, how will you determine which configuration to use?

Comment: It depends what values you are trying to modify. Please, add more details what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can do it in a 'declarative' manner via using different Attributes.

Comment: @salniro one of the API's is a nuget package so while I have access to the source code, it will be mounted programatically. The second API is already in my solution.

Comment: @sal niro might be onto something...

Comment: @ryudice have you looked into this? Could be helpful [per-controller-configuration-in-webapi](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/per-controller-configuration-in-webapi.aspx)